# Adding objects to 2D Vector in C++

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

I want to make a matrix using vector and instead of int I use objects of the class `Fraction`.

However, I am trying to add elements to it but with no luck so far.

```
class Fraction
{
public:
    int num;
    int den;

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, Fraction& fr);
    void operator= (const Fraction& fr);
};

ostream& operator << (ostream& os, Fraction& fr)
{
     os << fr.num << "/" << fr.den;

     return os;
}

void Fraction::operator=(const Fraction& fr)
{
    num = fr.num;
    den = fr.den;
}

int main()
{
    Fraction fr;

    int colunas = 2, linhas = 2;

    vector<vector<Fraction>> mat(linhas, vector<Fraction>(colunas));

    for (int i = 0; i < colunas; ++i)
    {
        cout << endl << "Coluna " << i + 1 << endl;

        for (int j = 0; j < linhas; ++j)
        {
            int x;
            vector<Fraction> temp;
            cin >> x;

            fr.num = x;
            fr.den = 1;

            temp.push_back(fr);

            mat.push_back(temp);
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    int len = mat.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat[i].size(); j++)
            {
                cout << mat[ i ] [ j ].num << " ";
            }

       cout << endl;
    }
}
```

With this I do iniatialize the matrix but it will only initialize to the rows.
It will be `mat[0][0]`, `mat[1][0]`, and if I try to access `mat[0][1]` it will give me garbage.

I have tried this line

```
mat[i][j] = temp;
```

but it throws an error:

> no matching operator =

**Edit:** following a suggestion and changing the code accordingly

```
class Fraction
{
public:
    int num;
    int den;

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, Fraction& fr);
    void operator= (const Fraction& fr);
};

ostream& operator << (ostream& os, Fraction& fr)
{
    os << fr.num << "/" << fr.den;

    return os;
}

void Fraction::operator=(const Fraction& fr)
{
    num = fr.num;
    den = fr.den;
}

int main()
{
    Fraction fr;

    int colunas = 2, linhas = 2;

    vector<vector<Fraction>> mat;//(linhas, vector<Fraction>(colunas));
    vector<Fraction> temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < colunas; ++i)
    {
        cout << endl << "Coluna " << i + 1 << endl;

        for (int j = 0; j < linhas; ++j)
        {
            int x;

            cin >> x;

            fr.num = x;
            fr.den = 1;

            temp.push_back(fr);
        }

        mat.push_back(temp);

        cout << endl;
    }

    //cout << mat[0][1];
    //cin.get();
    //cin.get();

    int len = mat.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat[i].size(); j++)
        {
            cout << mat[ i ] [ j ].num << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

What I want the code to do is the following:

when I run it this is how it behaves

input

```
34
3
2
4
```

output

```
34 3
34 3 2 4
```

That is not the output I expect however, the first two input numbers make up the first column and second two make up the second column. So the output should be like this:

Expected output

```
34 2
3 4
```

If I access `mat[0][1]` I expect it to give me `2/1` but instead it gives me `3/1`

Comment: Your `mat.push_back(temp)` is misplaced. Put it outside of the inner loop.

Comment: `void operator= (const Fraction& fr);` -- This function is totally unnecessary.  The compiler default assignment operator works perfectly without having to introduce a user-defined version.  Never write unnecessary code that the compiler will provide for you, bug free and optimized.

Comment: Don't do this: `void operator= (const Fraction& fr);` Assignments should be to a reference, not a void, so you can chain them like other uses of =. And Paul's comment above points out that this class works fine with the default assigment.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie actually I never wanted an assignment operator, I was just trying to see if by assigning the `temp`  variable directly into the position I wanted in the matrix would solve my problem and when it gave me the `no matching operator=` error I tried providing the assignment operator

Comment: You did not delcare `vector<Fraction> temp;` where I said you should...

Comment: @walnut thanks, I had noticed that but didn't think it would be make a difference.
The code works well.
From what I saw first you initialize the row and then add it to the matxi, is it possible to instead of row initialize the column and add it to the matrix??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `vector` constructor used in this line:

```
vector<vector<Fraction>> mat(linhas, vector<Fraction>(colunas));
```

fills the vector with `linhas` copies of `vector<Fraction>(colunas)`, which itself is a vector of `colunas` many default-constucted `Fraction`s.

`Faction`'s default constructor is implicitly defined (because you did not declare any constructor yourself) and it does nothing. It leaves the `int` members with indeterminate values.

`push_back` later adds new elements to the vectors, after the ones that are already there from the default constructed ones. `push_back` does not replace elements already in the vector.

You probably don't want to prefill the vector with default constructed elements, so just default-initialize `mat`, which will leave it empty. The later `push_back` calls will add elements to it:

```
vector<vector<Fraction>> mat;
```

---

As mentioned in the comments, you don't need to write a copy assignment operator. The compiler will generate one automatically for you that has the correct behavior.

---

If you want to avoid creating `Fraction` objects with uninitialized values, such as you do in the `mat` constructor, then you can write your own constructor (which will disable the implicitly declared one), e.g.:

```
class Fraction
{
public:
    int num;
    int den;

    Fraction(int num_, int den_) : num(num_), den(den_) {}

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, Fraction& fr);
    void operator= (const Fraction& fr);
};

//...

        for (int j = 0; j < linhas; ++j)
        {
            int x;
            vector<Fraction> temp;
            cin >> x;

            temp.push_back(Fraction(x, 1));

            mat.push_back(temp);
        }
```

Instead of `temp.push_back(Fraction(x, 1));` you can also write just `temp.push_back({x, 1});` or `temp.emplace_back(x, 1);`.

---

You probably also intend to collect one inner vector in the inner loop and add it to the outer vector, i.e.:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < colunas; ++i)
    {
        cout << endl << "Coluna " << i + 1 << endl;

        vector<Fraction> temp;
        for (int j = 0; j < linhas; ++j)
        {
            int x;
            cin >> x;

            temp.push_back(Fraction(x,1));
        }
        mat.push_back(temp);

        cout << endl;
    }
```

Comment: I changed the code so it equals your last snippet of code but it still doesn't behave like a matrix.

Comment: @HBatalha Then please add your current code after changes to the question and provide an example of the input you used, the output you got and the output you want. Don't remove or overwrite the current question contents, though.